# Problems with cluster's virtual IP

Tags: ip, virtual, heartbeat

I'm planning to implement an 99% high avalaibility cluster using heartbeat/corosync + pacemaker for communication between some servers, but these machines aren't into same gateway/netmask and i cannot share an virtual IP for heartbeat. There's a way to solve this without plugging all the servers into the same router (because its not an option)???

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 0):

An availability of 99% means that your system tolerates more than three and a half days of downtime a year. You should be able to achieve that availability with commodity hardware and without using pacemaker.

If you want higher availability or the possibility to do system maintenance without disrupting the service you're able to achieve higher uptime using DNS. You can either switch DNS records with low TTLs manually, or use a service like Amazon Route 53 to switch automatically if some kind of healthcheck fails for even more reliability.